# Android Camera, internal Listoption?

Tags: java, android, listview, camera, sd-card

When you are taking a picture on an and device, you can send it. There are apps, which are pushing their actions into these send-list (Like Twidroid, which adds a listitem called "Send Tweet" in that menu).

So, how is it possible to add such a menu point into that menu?
For my app, I want to make it possible to take pictures from both (The App itself and via the real camera-send-list) and save them on the sdcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, how is it possible to add such a
>   menu point into that menu?

Write an activity that implements an `ACTION_SEND` `<intent-filter>`, perhaps for camera-related MIME types.

Comment: Ok, search around and found some examples. But how to use the filter? When I take my main activity, and add this filter, what I have to put into the main-class to catch this sending-event?

Comment: Here is a sample application that supports `ACTION_SEND`, but for text, not images: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Introspection/FauxSender/

Comment: Oh, thats a very good example! So basically the OS is searching for ACTION-SEND's in the apps, and parsing them itself.
I think that helps me alot, thankees :)